# Unable to sign into StackOverflow iOS app

Tags: ios, google-signin

Trying to sign into the official iOS StackOverflow App using same gmail login I use here, but it gives a Request Failed error every time.

Any ideas would be appreciated

[Image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FLIs.jpg)

Comment: Pls add the issue here - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: In-fact its already there - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372621/unable-to-log-in-with-google-account-to-the-stack-overflow-ios-app-request-fail

Comment: Many thanks, I did search there but could not find this, so guess its not just me